# How can I get start of month in epoch form from random epoch timestamp in Perl?

Tags: perl, epoch, localtime

I get some times from a database and I am trying to store them by month, using the epoch form. 
So I could have some random times like:

```
1354120744
1328978360
1297388332
```

and for each one I want to find the epoch value which represents the 1st of that month 
so for the last timestamp it would be:

`1296518400` (using lovely `epochconverter.com`).

I know that I can use `POSIX mktime` to reduce the timestamp down to days, mins etc and change them accordingly etc as was the answer to a post I did a while ago: [How to go back months in Perl taking account of different days in month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176610/how-to-go-back-months-in-perl-taking-account-of-different-days-in-month)

The trouble I have with that is that while I can zero times, I'm worried that by changing the date the day of week will not match up, so essentially making an invalid date. This may be an unnecessary worry; I don't know if it would make a difference having the wrong day of week if the times are validated.

I couldn't see any other POSIX methods which seemed useful. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought would be to use [Time::Local](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Local) to convert the `localtime` results back to epoch, with the appropriate values forced to 0 or 1 as needed.  Note that day of week is not among the input values it expects, so you don't need to worry about what happens if you get that wrong.

`$start_of_month_epoch = timelocal(0, 0, 0, 1, $month, $year);`

Comment: and here I naively thought localtime and timelocal were the same... silly me! thanks :)

Comment: localtime and timelocal are opposites; localtime turns an epoch integer into the 6 (or 9) broken-down fields, and timelocal turns those 6 fields back into an epoch integer. They're great for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 9):

I stopped worrying about timestamp issues since I've met [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime):

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E 'say DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => 1354120744)->truncate(to => "month")->epoch;'
1351728000
```

Comment: Not bad module but timezones are hardcoded and it can segfault on daylight times

Comment: DateTime is The Way, but I think we need to respect time zone differences by giving `from_epoch` a `time_zone` argument.

Comment: seems to work well, but not as easy to understand without looking at documentation - interesting what @PSIAlt said

Comment: As the DateTime->from_epoch() docs state, "By default, the returned object will be in the UTC time zone.". Of course, you could state `DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => 1354120744, time_zone => "local")`

Comment: @darch epoch time(unix timestamp) is UTC so nothing to do with timezone. creaktive, i dont have code it was on my previous work. But there was something with datetime mathematics

Answer (score 1):

> The trouble I have with that is that while I can zero times, I'm worried that by changing the date the day of week will not match up, so essentially making an invalid date.

`mktime(3)` ignores the `wday`, `yday` and `isdst` fields for this exact reason. You can safely adjust the `mday` to 1 then call `POSIX::mktime()` again to turn it back to an epoch value.

```
my @t = localtime();
$t[0] = $t[1] = $t[2] = 0; # sec/min/hour
$t[3] = 1;                 # mday
my $epoch_start_of_month = mktime @t;
```

Or simpler

```
my $epoch = mktime 0, 0, 0, 1, (localtime)[4,5];
```